# Javascript : Update browser Internet Explorer from 8 to 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-11

I have updated the browser Internet Explorer from 8 version to 11 version.

Now this javascript function not working.

Can you please help me figure out the problem?

Thanks in advance.

```
<script language="JavaScript">

function sSend() { 
document.form.submit()
} 

</script>
</head>

<body onLoad="sSend()">
<form method="POST" name="form" action="http://....">
    <input type="hidden" name="USER" value="<%=strUSER%>">   
    <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="<%=strID%>"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="referer" value="<%=strReferer%>">
</form>
```

Comment: What errors do you get in the console?

Comment: @j08691 Hi, thank you for reply. I don't have error but the variables `strUser` and `strID` and `strReferer` are nulls.

Comment: My guess is they removed the *named elements are registered as global variables* "feature": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3434278/do-dom-tree-elements-with-ids-become-global-variables

Comment: @pawel — that code isn't using that feature, and they haven't.

Comment: @AntonioMailtraq — That looks like as ASP.NET problem, not a browser problem.

Comment: I don't use ASP NET it's in Classic ASP ....

Comment: @Quentin I think `document.form` clearly tries to reference `<form name="form">` by its name.

Comment: The three variables you mention in your comment all seem to be server-side variables, so whether they are null or not doesn't depend on the browser. Please be clearer about exactly what is happening that is unexpected.

Comment: @pawel — That isn't a global, and it is still supported.

Comment: @AntonioMailtraq — ASP.NET or Classic ASP, it still looks like a server side issue.

Comment: @Quentin Okay but if on IE 8 the server side language worked why it stops working with browser 11 ?

Comment: @AntonioMailtraq — We have no way of telling what your server side code is doing.

Comment: @Quentin On Server Side all it's ok. The values of variables are all correct

Comment: @AntonioMailtraq — How can they be correct if they are null as soon as you write them into the HTML? How are you determining that they are null? You originally said that the problem was with the JavaScript, but the JavaScript doesn't do anything with the values of the inputs.

Answer (score 1):

I think that your problem is not client side and not server side.

You log in to your web page using a favorite link?

Please try writing your web address on the address bar in the new browser and leave the favorite link.

Comment: I can't believe ... why I don't have thought ? ... :(